# How to stop a running Thread using a boolean flag is not working

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this code snippet. When I try to match a condition inside an `if` statement and if it's satisfied the `running` boolean value should be set to `false`. But it is (the `Thread`) still working. Can anyone please show me the error I'm doing?

```
    public void timer() {

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int min = 1;
                int sec = 10;
                System.out.println("--- " + min + " Minutes and " + sec + " Seconds ---");
                boolean running = true;
                while (running) {
                    System.gc();
                    try {                        
                        for (int i = sec; i <= 60; i--) {
                            if (i >= 0) {
                                System.out.println(min + " Minutes and " + i + " Seconds"); 
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } else {
                                i = 60;
                                min--;
                                if (min < 0) { //condition I'm checking
                                    System.out.println("OOOOOOOOOOOOOKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK"); 
                                    running=false; //while loop should be false and thread should not run anymore
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Everything is work fine. (**Even the "OKKKKKKKKK..." is printing too)**, but `running` is not setting to `false`.

Comment: running is definitely get set to false, you just never get to testing the `while` condition again. It's easier to just exit with a labeled `break` or even `return`. Your for loop never terminates.

Comment: The problem is that you set `i` to 60.  That means you will repeat the `for` loop another 60 times ... and again ... and again.  You never get back to the `while(running)` test.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Sir @StephenC

Comment: And thank you Sir @pvg

Answer (score 0):

At first, you set `i = min` (10)
then you're printing and waiting `if (i >= 0)`
and then you're setting `i = 60;`
and at the whole time `i` is decreasing (`i--`).
Notice that `i` would be `i <= 60;` as the `for` loop checks forever
so, `running` would be `false`, but would never be checked at the `while` loop

try to increase `i` for whatever you're trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your program logic you are setting value of running variable false in for loop and also resetting the value of i = 60 - running variable value is set to false but controll never return to while loop so the thread never terminates

Check this adding break statement do the trick and control return to while loop and thread terminated successfully

```
       new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int min = 1;
                int sec = 10;
                System.out.println("--- " + min + " Minutes and " + sec + " Seconds ---");
                boolean running = true;
                while (running) {
                    System.gc();
                    try {                        
                        for (int i = sec; i <= 60; i--) {
                            if (i >= 0) {
                                System.out.println(min + " Minutes and " + i + " Seconds"); 
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } else {
                                i = 60;
                                min--;
                                if (min < 0) { //condition I'm checking
                                    System.out.println("OOOOOOOOOOOOOKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK"); 
                                    running=false; //while loop should be false and thread should not run anymore
                                break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```